# How to pass looping value from controller to view

Tags: controller, codeigniter-3

I want to post looping value from controller to view, below are my controller.

```
 public function sendEverything($soapinput) {

    $soap = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ben=\"http://xmlns.oracle.com/aaaa\">
           <soapenv:Header/>
           <soapenv:Body>
               <ben:aaa>#aaa</ben:aaa>
                 <ben:bbb>#bbb</ben:bbb>
                 <ben:ccc>#ccc</ben:ccc>
           </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $soapexplode = explode("\r\n",$soapinput);


    for ($i=0;$i<count($soapexplode);$i++) {

        $loopvar = explode(',',$soapexplode[$i]);
        //var_dump($loopvar);

        $loopmsg = str_replace("#aaa",trim($loopvar['0']),$soap);
        $loopmsg = str_replace("#bbb",trim($loopvar['1']),$loopmsg);
        $loopmsg = str_replace("#ccc",trim($loopvar['2']),$loopmsg);

        //echo $loopvar[0];
        $result = $this->nusoap_client->send($loopmsg,'process',30,30);

        if($this->nusoap_client->fault)
        {
             $text = 'Error: '.$this->nusoap_client->fault;
             echo $text;
        }
        else
        {
            if ($this->nusoap_client->getError())
            {
                 $text = 'Error: '.$this->nusoap_client->getError();
                 echo $text;
            }
                else
                {
                    $data['msisdn'] = $loopvar[0];
                    $data['result'] = ($result['result'] === 0) ? 'Failed' : 'Success';

                    $this->load->view('content', 'soap/soapEverythingResult', $data);
                }
        }   
    }

 }
```

but this code only show last records of array if i post the $data to view.

but if this line

`$this->load->view('content', 'soap/soapEverythingResult', $data);`

i change with this

```
echo "Result Status for send everything &nbsp;". $loopvar[0]."&nbsp; is &nbsp;". $data['result']. "<br>";
```

it show looping value, let says the input 3 it will show 3 value. like this below result

```
Result Status for send everything aaa is success
Result Status for send everything bbb is success
Result Status for send everything ccc is success
```

My expected result is like above

Comment: are you sending a looping data to the model for database and then you want that data back to the controller and then view. am I correct?? @Amir Rachman

Comment: @ankit i'm not taken data from model, it was taken from soap response, and given response i want pass it to the view with array, i've try but it was only given last array withy above code

Comment: You can add multiple array on the loded view by this :

$this->load->view('admin/prop_master_insert', ['city_list' => $city_list, 'state_list' => $state_list, 'all_amenities' => $all_amenities, 'developer_list' => $developer_list, 'customer_list' => $customer_list]);

Comment: here I passed the city list, state list, and other data to my view.  is this helpful sir? @Amir Rachman

Comment: hi @ankitsuthar can you use 'answer question' rather then use this add comment, i try your suggestions but it's not working..